# Filteration on dataframe column value with combination of values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe which has 2 columns named **TABLEID** and **STATID**
There are different values in the both the columns.
when I filter the dataframe on values say '101PC' and 'ST101', it gives me 14K records and when I filter the dataframe on values say '102HT' and 'ST102', it gives me 14K records also. The issue is when I try to combine both the filters like below it gives me blank dataframe. I was expecting 28K records in my resultant dataframe. Any help is much appreciated

```
df[df[['TABLEID','STATID']].apply(tuple, axis = 1).isin([('101PC', 'ST101'), ('102HT','ST102')])]
```

Comment: Should work, so either there's a typo or some white space ruining the comparison. Once you figure that out, a `merge` would be more performant to subset, but will likely be plagued by the same issue if the above isn't working.

Comment: @ALollz....i checked it many times, there is no typo and white spaces I already taken care. Why do I have to merge? Do you mean to say that i can get two results dataframes and merge them?

Comment: I tested with small number of entries, it works too!

Comment: No I mean that `.apply(tuple, axis = 1)` is _very slow_. Instead you can do an inner merge which is logically the same. I.e. `df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame([('101PC', 'ST101'), ('102HT','ST102')], columns=['TABLEID','STATID']))` will do the same subset but will be very efficient. Maybe stupid question but are you sure 'TABLEID' is the column that takes the value '101PC' and not "STATID'?

Comment: @ALollz...yes TABLEID is the column that takes the value '101PC' and STATID takes 'ST101'

Comment: @SeaBean... I was sure that it will work, but something is not coming correctly here.

Comment: Well can you provide sample data from your DataFrame that reproduces the problem? (preferabbly using `df.head().to_dict()` so we get the exact values in your Frame. Otherwise there's not much else to say because your code _should_ work.

Comment: Here is my dataset.. 

TABID | STATID
------------------
101PC | ST10
102PC |   ST1022
103PC | ST103
101PC | ST10
102PC | ST1022
102PC | ST1022

I filtered based on both condition which i posed. The STATID column value is 6 characters, so while filtering based on ST10 I am putting 4 characters spaces.